# create dummy load date table based on modified date in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

This is more like record comparison. How to I add end date here? Note that the last date comes from tableB. Example:

**TableA**

```
PROD     | PRICE | EffDATE
----------------------------- 
Product1 | $15   | 03/17/2015  
Product1 | $20   | 03/20/2015  
Product1 | $21   | 03/22/2015
```

**TableB**

```
PROD     | PROMOSTART | PROMOEND
----------------------------------
Product1 | 03/17/2015 | 03/24/2015
```

**Output expected:**

```
 PROD     | PRICE | StartDATE  | EndDATE 
-----------------------------------------
Product1 | $15   | 03/17/2015  | 03/19/2015
Product1 | $20   | 03/20/2015  | 03/21/2015
Product1 | $21   | 03/22/2015  | **03/24/2015**
```

How do I achieve this in **`Teradata SQL`**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.*,
   COALESCE(MIN(EffDATE) -- next row's date
            OVER (PARTITION BY a.PROD
                  ORDER BY EffDATE
                  ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING) -1
           ,b.PROMOEND)  -- or end of promo
FROM tableA AS a
JOIN tableB AS b
  ON a.PROD = b.PROD
 AND a.EffDATE BETWEEN b.PROMOSTART AND b.PROMOEND
```

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks a ton dnoeth.. You're a savior!!